# VisualStudioの参照設定で同名プロジェクトの参照は可能なのか？

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

ソリューション構成図のように、Viewsプロジェクトから、ソリューション内の異なるパスに存在する同名プロジェクト(ViewModels)を参照したいです。しかし、VisualStudioの参照設定から両プロジェクトにチェック入れてを参照すると、エラーポップアップが出てどちらか一つのプロジェクトしか参照できません。
同名プロジェクトをあるプロジェクトから参照することは可能なのでしょうか？
手段が間違っているならば、手段が知りたいです。

環境：VisualStudio2017、.Net4.6.1、C#

**ソリューション構成図**
[image: ソリューション構成図]

Comment: GUIDで区別しているということらしいので、@sayuri さん回答の仕組み等で対応できるのでしょうね。[Two same project name with one renamed in the same solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9cfea9ea-772b-492c-a232-c3a116463ae2)

Comment: VS2013かVS2015あたりから変わっており、同名プロジェクトはVS IDEで参照追加できません。
アセンブリ名が異なっていてもプロジェクト名が同じだと参照設定に追加できないことになるので、プロジェクト名を分けていただくしかないかと思っています。
（例：Abc\Hoge.csproj (Abc.Hoge.dll) と Def\Hoge.csproj (Def.Hoge.dll) がある場合、どちらか一方しか参照できません。VS2019で確認）

Comment: 確かに、調べたらこんな記事を見つけました。[visual studio: multiple projects with same name in one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49968642/9014308) @Azulean さん指摘の状況のようです。他にクラス名なら何か技があるかもみたいな記事もあります。[Is one solution with multiple projects using the same class names in each project possible?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6ac55df2-e6a7-4ddf-a23c-be0eccd7d493)

Comment: ＠Azuleanさん、@kunifさん　VisualStudioのバグなのですね...同名プロジェクトの参照はあきらめて、プロジェクト名を変更して参照しようと思います。

Answer (score 2):

C#言語には[`extern alias`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias)という機能があり、全く同名のアセンブリ・名前空間・クラスを区別して扱うことができます。

その上でVisual Studio上で参照している当該アセンブリのプロパティを表示すると`Aliases: global`という項目がありますがここが`extern alias`の設定個所ですので、それぞれに別名を付けてあげてください。

Comment: extern aliasで別名を指定すれば、全く同名のアセンブリ・名前空間・クラスを区別して扱うことができることは了解しました。しかし、VisualStudioの同名プロジェクトの参照チェックができないことにより、当該アセンブリのプロパティを表示しても片方のViewModelsプロジェクトのアセンブリしか表示されないため、extern aliasの設定すらできません。